# Why does shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation getting called several times?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I have noticed that shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation on my viewcontrollers are getting called several times.

It must be the device calling it because I am not.

Any ideas?

Comment: they are getting called randomly? or the device is being rotated?

Comment: same question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2621702/shouldautorotatetointerfaceorientation-called-several-times-in-a-row-without-any?rq=1  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10768524/on-ios-why-is-shouldautorotatetointerfaceorientation-called-10-12-or-13-times?rq=1

Comment: Of course it's the device (the OS) calling this method - you should not call it yourself.

Comment: possible duplicate of [rotate a UIView around its center but several times](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/518530/rotate-a-uiview-around-its-center-but-several-times)